# numpy append_field gives shape error for new field with 2d shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a structured numpy array, I want to use the recfunctions library
http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.recfunctions.html
function append_fields() or rec_append_fields() to append a field with some
shape to it.  However, I get an error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (10,3)

where `10` is the length of my existing array, and `(3,)` is the shape of the field I want to append.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields


my_structured_array = np.array(
    zip([0,1,2,3],[[4.3,3.2],[1.4,5.6],[6.,2.5],[4.5,5.4]]),
    dtype=[('id','int8'),('pos','2float16')]
    )
my_new_field = np.ones(
    len(my_structured_array),
    dtype='2int8'
    )
my_appended_array = append_fields(
    my_structured_array,
    'new',
    data=my_new_field
    )
```

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4) (4,2)

Any ideas?  I tried making `my_new_field` a list of tuples and putting a dtype
argument with the proper shape into the append_fields():

```
my_new_field = len(my_structured_array)*[(1,1)]

my_appended_array = append_fields(
    my_structured_array,
    'new',
    data=my_new_field,
    dtype='2int8'
    )
```

but that seems to end up the same once it gets converted to a numpy array.

None of this seems to change when I use rec_append_fields() instead of simply
append_fields()

EDIT:
In light of the fact that my new field doesn't have the same shape as my array, I suppose that my desired append is impossible, suggested by [@radicalbiscuit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895755/radicalbiscuit).

```
In : my_new_field.shape
Out: (4, 2)

In : my_structured_array.shape
Out: (4,)
```

But, I included one of the original fields in the array with shape different from the original array to make my point, which is that a field does not have to have the same shape as the structured array.  How can I append a field like this?

```
In : my_structured_array['pos'].shape
Out: (4, 2)

In : my_new_field.shape
Out: (4, 2)
```

I should note that for my application, I can append an empty field as long as it's possible to somehow change the shape later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`append_fields()` does indeed require that the two arrays be the same shape. That being said, as you realized in `my_structured_array`, numpy does support subarrays (that is, a field can itself be an array with a shape).

In your case, I think you probably want `my_new_field` not to be a two dimensional array, but instead be a one dimensional array (of shape `shape(my_structured_array)`) with elements of dtype, e.g., `dtype([('myfield', '<i8', (2,))])`. For example,

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields

my_structured_array = np.array(
    zip([0,1,2,3],[[4.3,3.2],[1.4,5.6],[6.,2.5],[4.5,5.4]]),
    dtype=[('id','int8'),('pos','2float16')]
    )

my_new_field = np.ones(
    len(my_structured_array),
    dtype=[('myfield', 'i8', 2)]
    )

my_appended_array = append_fields(
    my_structured_array,
    'new',
    data=my_new_field
    )
```

Will yield,

```
>>> my_appended_array[0]
(0, [4.30078125, 3.19921875], ([1, 1],))
```

Although the datatype is slightly inconvenient as `myfield` is nested within `new`,

```
>>> my_appended_array.dtype
dtype([('id', '|i1'), ('pos', '<f2', (2,)), ('new', [('myfield', '<i8', (2,))])])
```

This, however, is coerced away fairly easily,

```
>>> np.asarray(my_appended_array, dtype=[('id', '|i1'), ('pos', '<f2', (2,)), ('myfield', '<i8', (2,))])
array([(0, [4.30078125, 3.19921875], [0, 0]),
       (1, [1.400390625, 5.6015625], [0, 0]), (2, [6.0, 2.5], [0, 0]),
       (3, [4.5, 5.3984375], [0, 0])], 
      dtype=[('id', '|i1'), ('pos', '<f2', (2,)), ('myfield', '<i8', (2,))])
```

Still, it's a bit unfortunate that we've had to repeat the dtype of `my_structured_array` here. While at first glance it appears that `numpy.lib.recfunctions.flatten_descr` could do the dirty work of flattening the dtype, it unfortunately gives a tuple and not a list as required by `np.dtype`. Coercing its output to a list, however, works around this issue,

```
>>> np.dtype(list(np.lib.recfunctions.flatten_descr(my_appended_array.dtype)))
dtype([('id', '|i1'), ('pos', '<f2', (2,)), ('myfield', '<i8', (2,))])
```

This can be passed as the dtype to `np.asarray`, making things slightly more robust against changes in `my_structured_array.dtype`.

Indeed, minor inconsistencies such as this make working with record arrays messy business. One gets the feeling that things could fit together a bit more coherently.

*Edit:*
It turns out that the `np.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays` function is much more amenable to this sort of merging,

```
 >>> my_appended_array = merge_arrays([my_structured_array, my_new_field], flatten=True)
 array([(0, [4.30078125, 3.19921875], [1, 1]),
        (1, [1.400390625, 5.6015625], [1, 1]), (2, [6.0, 2.5], [1, 1]),
        (3, [4.5, 5.3984375], [1, 1])], 
       dtype=[('id', '|i1'), ('pos', '<f2', (2,)), ('myfield', '<i8', (2,))])
```

Comment: So, it seems that using a named field in my_new_field is the key, but that gives the nested dtypes.  I think that if the new field must have a shape, then the best thing is to create a new array and then merge or join the two similarly shaped structured arrays as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355744/numpy-joining-structured-arrays

Answer (score 2):

`append_fields()` requires that the two arrays are the same shape, which in this case they are not. Printing out the two arrays will help it become obvious:

```
>>> my_structured_array
array([(0, [4.30078125, 3.19921875]), (1, [1.400390625, 5.6015625]),
       (2, [6.0, 2.5]), (3, [4.5, 5.3984375])], 
      dtype=[('id', '|i1'), ('pos', '<f2', (2,))])
>>> my_new_field
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

As you can see, `my_structured_array` is an array of length 4 where each element is a tuple containing two objects, an int and a list of two floats.

`my_new_field`, on the other hand, is an array of length 4 where each element is a list of two ints. It's like trying to add apples and oranges.

Make your arrays the same shape and they'll add together.

Comment: But my understanding is that a field in array can have a shape different from the structured array:

    In : my_new_field.shape
    Out: (4, 2)

    In : my_structured_array.shape
    Out: (4,)

    In : my_structured_array['pos'].shape
    Out: (4, 2)

How can I append a field that is similar in shape to one of the fields already in the array?