# Adding columns to a structured Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data in `geo.dat`

```
id  lon  lat inhab  name
 1   9.  45.   100  Ciriè
 2  10.  45.    60  Acquanegra
```

and I get it in a `ndarray`

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('geo.dat', dtype=None, names=True)
```

so far, so good, I have a data structure that I can address by column name

```
print(data['name'][1]) #>>> Acquanegra
```

Next step, and question — I have a function that takes in input two vectors of
geographical coordinates (`data['LON']` and `data['LAT']` of course) and returns two arrays `x` and `y` of projected positions on a map (this works ok).

I can live with separate vectors `x` and `y` but I'd like to augment `data` with two new columns, `data['x']` and `data['y']`. My naive attempt

```
data['x'], data['y'] = convert(data['LON'], data['LAT'])
```

raised a `ValueError: no field of name x`, teaching me that `data` has some traits of a dictionary but a dictionary is not.

Is it possible to do as I want? tia

Please consider that `.hstack()` doesn't work with structured arrays aka record arrays, most previous answers work only for homogeneous arrays (the exception is mentioned in below comment by Warren).

---

PS I'd prefer not to `pandas`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427197/numpy-add-column-to-existing-array/25429497#25429497

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser AH! I suspected that the key was to manipulate the `.dtype` of the array but I would had never devised all the steps involved... I've upvoted your answer of course.  May I ask you if my title "structured array" is terminologically correct?  If yes, I'd like to answer my question summarizing your answer and giving a link to it because I feel that the title of the question you answered is a bit generic.

Comment: But then you would be creating a duplicate question, and stackoverflow frowns on that.   It would be better to edit the title of the other question.  In fact, I'll do that right now...

Comment: The key point about `hstack` or other `concatenate` functions is that dtype fields are not an axis (even though there some similarities in data layout). 
 `reshape` also doesn't work  across that axis/field boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.lib.recfunctions`:

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

data = rfn.append_fields(data, ['x', 'y'], [x, y])
```

Comment: Works.  Sort of.  The array returned by `rfn.append_fields()` is a collection of _masked_ arrays, while previously both the columns of `data` and the arrays returned by `transform()` were non-masked arrays.  Could you mention in your answer the origin and the (possible) implications of this unexpected nehaviour? —— Further, you may want to add your answer to the question mentioned by Warren in a comment to my question, because I feel that my question is going to be closed...

Comment: To comment on my comment, the optional argument `usemask=False` could take care of my issue...

Comment: `rfn.append_fields` performs the same kind of action as `@Warren's` link - make a new array of desired dtype and size and copy fields by name.  It is more general in that it allows for missing data, can make `masked_arrays` and can make `recarrays`.

Comment: `recfunctions` are a bit buggy, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364725/numpy-recarray-append-fields-cant-append-numpy-array-of-datetimes; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769632/numpy-recfunctions-join-by-typeerror.  They aren't heavily used, and interact with other array subclasses.