# merge numpy array together

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

```
a1=array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
a2=array([[0, 1],
   [2, 3]])
a3 = array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3]])
```

I have two arrays a1,a2，I want to merge them together.the result is a3

Comment: See [Numpy: Joining structured arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5355744/1761793)

Comment: Also, [Concatenate two arrays vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21887754/1761793) has your answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy `np.concatenate()` this way should work

```
 a3 = np.concatenate((a1,a2),axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.c_[a1, a2]`

also a `np.r_` for row-wise merging.