# Combining two numpy ndarray arrays with named fields

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

How do I properly combine two numpy ndarrays that have named fields and are the same length into one ndarray?  In my example below I would like to combine `xnd` and `ynd` into a single numpy ndarray.

I know how to create a new ndarray from the concatenated dtype of `xnd` and `ynd` and then iteratively copy the contents from `xnd` and `ynd` into that new ndarray.  But is there a numpy command that will do this for me?

The fastest and simplest way of combining `xnd` and `ynd` would be ideal.  Perhaps appending `ynd` to `xnd` inplace rather than making a copy?  This solution needs to work fast with large ndarrays.

I have seen several examples on how to combine simple n dimensional numpy arrays, but they haven't helped me with this problem.  The line with `znd = np.join((xnd, ynd))` at the bottom of my example is where I get stuck.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

n = 10

t = np.arange(n)
abc = np.array((t,t+n,t+2*n)).T
y = (t*10).astype(np.uint32) 


# Create x ndarray
xdt = np.dtype([
    ('t', np.float64),
    ('abc', (np.float32, 3) )
    ])
xnd = np.ndarray( shape=n, dtype=xdt)
xnd['t'] = t
xnd['abc'] = abc

# Create y ndarray
ydt = np.dtype([
    ('y', np.uint32),
    ])
ynd = np.ndarray( shape=n, dtype=ydt)
ynd['y'] = y


print xnd.dtype
# [('t', '<f8'), ('abc', '<f4', (3,))]
print ynd.dtype
# [('y', '<u4')]


# Combine x and y
# This line not correct.  What is the proper way to do this?
znd = np.join((xnd, ynd)) 

print znd.dtype
# [('t', '<f8'), ('abc', '<f4', (3,)), ('y', '<u4')]
```

Comment: My question was a duplicate and already answered here: [Numpy: Joining structured arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355744/numpy-joining-structured-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the `recarray` functions do - copy fields by name:

```
In [10]: zdt=[('t', '<f8'), ('abc', '<f4', (3,)), ('y', '<u4')]
In [11]: znd=np.zeros(xnd.shape, dtype=zdt)

In [12]: for name in xnd.dtype.names:
   ....:     znd[name]=xnd[name]
   ....:     

In [13]: for name in ynd.dtype.names:
    znd[name]=ynd[name]
   ....:     

In [14]: znd
Out[14]: 
array([(0.0, [0.0, 10.0, 20.0], 0L), (1.0, [1.0, 11.0, 21.0], 10L),
       (2.0, [2.0, 12.0, 22.0], 20L), (3.0, [3.0, 13.0, 23.0], 30L),
       (4.0, [4.0, 14.0, 24.0], 40L), (5.0, [5.0, 15.0, 25.0], 50L),
       (6.0, [6.0, 16.0, 26.0], 60L), (7.0, [7.0, 17.0, 27.0], 70L),
       (8.0, [8.0, 18.0, 28.0], 80L), (9.0, [9.0, 19.0, 29.0], 90L)], 
      dtype=[('t', '<f8'), ('abc', '<f4', (3,)), ('y', '<u4')])
```

Since normally the number of records is much larger than the number of fields, this iteration is not expensive.

There may be function that creates the union `zdt` from the individual ones, but I'm not going to dig around for that now.

There is a function that does the field copy recursively.  That's needed if the `dtype` is nested - fields with compound dtypes.

You can also create a new array from a list of tuples - one tuple per record.  Here I am using `zip()` to iterate on the 2 arrays, and joining their records with tuple concatenation.

```
np.array([tuple(x)+tuple(y) for x,y in zip(xnd,ynd)],dtype=zdt)
```

I expect this to be slower, at least when there more rows than fields.

---

Since there's no overlap in fields in this case, the new dtype can be made by just concatating `dtye.descr` of the dtypes.  `descr` is a list; one list can be joined to another.

```
In [26]: np.dtype(xnd.dtype.descr+ynd.dtype.descr)
Out[26]: dtype([('t', '<f8'), ('abc', '<f4', (3,)), ('y', '<u4')])
```